# How to monitor icloud backup progress?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

How to monitor icloud back up progress?

I have left my phone plugged in and locked for four or five nights now. The backup has still not completed, but my icloud usage is around 45GB according to `https://www.icloud.com/#settings`. Does this mean the 45GB of data has successfully been transferred to icloud? Or that 45GB of space has been allocated, but all the data has not necessarily been transferred yet? When I go to icloud photos, they seem to be more or less all there, but I don't know if they are the full versions of each photo.

When I try to manually back up, it changes from "9 hours remaining", to "7 hours remaining", to "11 hours remaining", etc., even when I leave the phone plugged in overnight.

Comment: For future reference, iCloud Photo Library uploads are a separate process from iCloud Backup. If both are taking place at the same time then your speed will be cut in half. Alsom everything you see in your photo library at iCloud.com is always the full-resolution version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 5 days you might need to figure out where the backup is hanging. 45 gb means you have significant data getting backed up. Also, there’s not a good way to monitor things, so you might need a a [split half search](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=420908&seqNum=3).

In this case I would disable backup of half the items and then see if backup completes in an hour or two. If not, disable half of the remaining items and repeat.

See this article for how to selectively back up some apps and data. - https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204247

Once the backup succeeds, re-enable things half by half.

Worst case the backup never works and you have to back up to iTunes. Best case the smaller backup gets you past the log jam.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know at the moment to monitor an icloud backup is still the progress bar on the iphone under: Settings > Apple ID (i.e. your name, first button in settings) > iCloud > iCloud back up.

**If there is a better or more detailed way to monitor icloud backup progress, post it here and I would be happy to mark it as the accepted answer**

(Click backup now to see progress bar). If that progress bar is stuck or the time never goes down, you may have the same problem I had. I fixed it by disabling all the apps from the backup and then enabling apps one by one

Settings > Apple ID (i.e. your name, first button in settings) > iCloud > iCloud > tap on storage bar chart > Manage storage > Backups > and then disable all the apps under, "Choose data to back up", then renable one by one (or in groups) once you have a successful back up.

Hattip: @bmike's answer above and:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6021379?start=0&tstart=0